# Visual Studio referenced assembly CopyLocal doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, .net-assembly

I have a `Console` application and a `Class Library` in a solution. Whenever I reference class library from console application it finds it but after building the solution it cannot find the type.

Although `CopyLocal` is set to `true` but the referenced assembly is not copied !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason was my console application target framework was `Client Profile`. Changing it to .NET 4.0 resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Is the referenced assembly in the Global Assembly Cache? Assemblies that are installed in the GAC are not copied to the output folder, even when CopyLocal is true.

Comment: No. It's an assembly of mine. I checked folder security and permission is granted.

Comment: You can also turn up the MSBuild logging level through the Visual Studio configuration which may indicate why the referenced assembly is not being copied.

Comment: This solves mine issue, is there any opportunity to copy assembly even though it's in GAC?

Comment: It would also be interesting to know which application installed it in the GAC (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861155/how-to-tell-which-applications-have-a-given-assembly-registered-in-the-gac).